# Can .htaccess be used to filter a white list?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, whitelist

Is there a way of generating a white list of acceptable files or types? I have seen recipes for rejecting file requests — is it possible to reject all but those from a list?

The sort of white list I had in mind would be something like:

```
*.html;*.jpg;*.css;*.php
```

… etc

I would assume that other file requests could result in a 404 File Not Found

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a whitelist like this in your root .htaccess:

```
# deny everything first
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from  all

# then allow selected whitelisted extensions
<FilesMatch '\.(php|html|jpe?g|css|js)$'>
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

---

**EDIT:** To return 404 for non-whitelisted files use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule !\.(php|html|jpe?g|css|js)$ - [L,NC,R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It appears to work, but is there a way of returning a 404 File not Found error rather than a 403 Forbidden?

Comment: That’s what I wanted, but I can see this interfering with Friendly URL rewriting: I currently use `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]`. Is there a way to do both? (I think the answer is no).